# Proper sorted display in full text indexing php

Tags: php, html, mysql

The following is my query:-

```
SELECT 
  author,
  (
   (MATCH(author) AGAINST('Anna Selby' in BOOLEAN MODE) * 20) +
   (MATCH(title) AGAINST('Anna Selby' in BOOLEAN MODE) * 10) +
   (MATCH(series) AGAINST('Anna Selby' in BOOLEAN MODE) * 5)) as score
FROM 
  search 
WHERE 
  MATCH(author,title,series) AGAINST('Anna Selby' in BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY
  score DESC
```

Everything is working fine but the problem is that whenever i search for the author name 'A selby', the results having 'Anna Selby' are displayed first and then the results having 'A selby'.

Is there any way by which i could make sure that 'A Selby' results are displayed before 'Anna Selby'. when i checked the scores, i found that Both 'Anna Selby' results, and 'A Selby' results have the same score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try ammending condition to :

```
ORDER BY
  score DESC, author ASC;
```